# Data loss with SQLite database in Delphi

Tags: sqlite, delphi

I am trying to save binary encoded data in SQLite database and I am able to save the values but there are few characters that are getting lost after saving and closing the dataset.

The inserted data looks like this.

[image]

The highlighted text is getting lost when I load the saved record in a grid or table.

**Create SQLite connection:**

```
procedure CreateSQLiteDB(ASQLiteDB: string);
begin
  FDConnection1.Params.Values['Database'] := 'DB_MOBILE';
  FDConnection1.Connected := true;
end;
```

**Copy table schema from an existing dataset:**

```
procedure CopyTableSchemaFrom(ADataset: TDataset;
  ATableNm: string);
var
  i: Integer;
  AField: TField;

  procedure L_CopyFieldDefToSQLiteTable(AName: string; aType: TDataType;
    ASize: Integer; AIsRqrd: Boolean);
  var
    LFldSz: Integer;
  begin
    LFldSz:= 0;
    case aType of
      ftString, ftWideString, ftBCD, ftBytes, ftVarBytes, ftBlob, ftMemo, ftGraphic: LFldSz:= ASize;
    end;

    tblSQLite.FieldDefs.Add(AName, aType, LFldSz, AIsRqrd);
  end;

begin
  if ADataset = nil then
    Assert(false, 'Unassigned argument supplied in ADataset.');
  if Trim(ATableNm) = '' then
    Assert(false, 'Empty argument supplied in ATableNm.');

  // SQLite Table name should be same as .DBF file name
  tblSQLite.TableName := ATableNm;

  { Loop through the field in source dataset and copy them to SQLite table. }
  for i := 0 to ADataset.FieldCount - 1 do
  begin
    AField := ADataset.Fields[i];
    if AField = nil then
      Continue;

    L_CopyFieldDefToSQLiteTable(AField.FieldName, AField.DataType,
      AField.DataSize, AField.Required);
  end;

  tblSQLite.CreateDataSet;
end;
```

**Copy value from existing dataset to SQLite;**

```
procedure CopyDataFrom(ASrc: TDataset;
  ASQLiteTblNm: string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if ASrc = nil then
    Assert(false, 'Unassigned argument supplied in ASrc.');
  if Trim(ASQLiteTblNm) = '' then
    Assert(false, 'Empty argument supplied in ASQLiteTblNm.');

  tblSQLite.Close;
  tblSQLite.CachedUpdates := true;
  tblSQLite.Active := true;

  ASrc.First;
  while not ASrc.Eof do
  begin
    tblSQLite.Insert;

    for i := 0 to ASrc.FieldCount - 1 do
    begin
      tblSQLite.Fields[i].Value := ASrc.Fields[i].Value;
    end;

    ASrc.Next;
  end;

  tblSQLite.ApplyUpdates;
  tblSQLite.CommitUpdates;
end;
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without more facts.  Which  TDataSet descendant type are you using with your dataset, and which Delphi version are you using?  Meanwhile, -1.

Comment: Add the code that you're using for inserting data into the database + the create statement for the database table + the delphi version you're using + the SQLite version you're using + the connection string and we might have an answerable question. As it stands I can only guess.

Comment: @MartynA, I have added code snippet and I am using FireDAC components to deal with all this processing. SQLite version I am using is SQLite3.

Comment: Still not very clear. What type of field are you using? Binary?

Comment: Much improved, now please add the create table statement that contains the column with the garbage in it and these question should be answerable.

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue. This was related to a property, StrsTrim of FireDAC dataset. Setting it FALSE has resolved the issue.